# How do I populate and associative array using php and mysql

Tags: arrays, building

How would I add elements to the below array?

/// BUILD CROSS REFERENCE ARRAY FOR PARENT COMPANY NAMES OF SUBCATEGORIES///

```
$newArray = array();
$comp_names = "SELECT company_name, company_id FROM pe_company_access";
$name_results = mysql_query($comp_names, $dbcnx);

while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_results)) 
{
    $newArray = array($row5["company_id"] => $row5["company_name"]);

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

I say, you should go with:

```
while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_results)) 
{
    $newArray[$row5["company_id"]] = $row5["company_name"];
}
```

That way you have `company_id` as a key of associative array, and `company_name` as value. But if you want to have sub arrays, indexed with 0 based index, you need to do following:

```
while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_results)) 
{
    $newArray[] = array($row5["company_id"] => $row5["company_name"]);
}
```